# Xslt get value of created xml element

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:when test="conditon = 'value1'">
    <typeId>4</typeId>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="conditon = 'value2'">
    <typeId>4</typeId>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="conditon = 'value3'">
    <typeId>4</typeId>
</xsl:when>
....
....
```

I have something like above.
Now I want to check condition on created xml tag (typeId).
i.e, below condition in xslt file,

```
<xsl:if test="$typeId = 4">
<price>100</price>
</xsl:if>
```

So, how can I use above condition on created tag (above typeId is created tag on which I want to make condition)

Or any other way to achieve as above?

Answer (score 1):

`$typeId` refers to a variable named `typeId`, and not to any element you have created.

What you can do, is define a variable called `typeId` that is set to just the value you want, and use that variable to create the element, and to check in your condition.

```
<xsl:variable name="typeId">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="conditon = 'value1'">1</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="conditon = 'value2'">2</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="conditon = 'value4'">4</xsl:when>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<typeId>
  <xsl:value-of select="$typeId" />
</typeId>

<xsl:if test="$typeId = 4">
  <price>100</price>
</xsl:if>
```

Do note that this code would have to be in the same block of code, as the `typeId` variable will be local in scope to that block.

Comment: Yes i can use as above, but i have to rewrite lots of condition to get variable typeId.
Isn't there any way to direct access created tag <typeId> in xslt? so i can directly make condition on that.

Comment: No, you can't access something that has been added to the result tree. You would need to store it in a variable first before outputting it.

Comment: Can i put any variable or anything in already existing conditions as i will get some variable true or false at bottom. So i can make condition upon that variable as its true or false, and if its true than <price>100</price>